# Установить номер элемента в зависимости от колличества столбцов и элементов в каждом

Tags: математика, pug

Есть 5 столбцов, 7 элементов на каждый, всего 32 элемента доступно.

Каждому элементу списка нужно присвоить номер класса, в зависимости от столбца, в который попадает.

Как это сделать в цикле:

```
each item in items
    - col = 'col-' + i*3/7
```

Что должно быть вместо "i*3/7" ?

Comment: Может `i / 5`? И, если не секрет, какой это язык?

Comment: @diraria Спасибо, но так не работает. Pug(бывш. Jade) -- pugjs.org

Comment: Может ещё заменить `each item in  items` на `each item, i in items`? По крайней мере в [документации](https://pugjs.org/language/iteration.html) цикл с индексом выглядит так.

Comment: @diraria да, спасиБо! верно подмечено.

Comment: @diraria Math.floor(i/7) +1;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Округляем i/7 и добавляем 1:

```
Math.floor(i/7) +1;
```